# Disable the entire wordlist

Tags: cocoa

My Cocoa application uses NSTexView. It is more or less like an editor. In the editor, it is possible for the user to type something like pro and hit the escape key. If the user does that he gets a list of all words that begin with pro. Is there a way to disable this ?.

Answer (score 0):

Implement this method in your text view's delegate and return nil.

> (NSArray *)textView:(NSTextView *)textView completions:(NSArray *)words forPartialWordRange:(NSRange)charRange indexOfSelectedItem:(NSInteger *)index

This should do the job for you.